# Issue with `background-repeat` not working in React component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm encountering a problem with the `background-repeat` property in my React component. I've set the `backgroundRepeat` property to "repeat," but it doesn't seem to be functioning as expected. The background image does not repeat as it should. I'm using the following style for the background:

```
const backgroundStyle = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH}/assets/jadwal/BackgroundPertandingan.png)`,
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
  backgroundPosition: 'center top',
  backgroundRepeat: 'repeat',
}
```

```
<div>
      <div className="overflow-hidden">
        <main
          className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center bg-repeat pb-64 pt-[5%] "
          style={backgroundStyle}
        >
          {jadwalFiltered.map((jadwal, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="mb-8">
              <JadwalCard
                team1={jadwal.attributes.tim1}
                team2={jadwal.attributes.tim2}
                date={format(new Date(jadwal.attributes.datetime), 'dd MMMM')}
                time={new Date(jadwal.attributes.datetime).toLocaleTimeString([], {
                  hour: '2-digit',
                  minute: '2-digit',
                  hour12: false,
                })}
                location={jadwal.attributes.tempat}
                cabor={jadwal.attributes.olahraga}
                kategori={jadwal.attributes.kategori}
                linktempat={jadwal.attributes.linktempat}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I expected the background image to repeat, but it remains as a single instance. How can I fix this issue and make the background image repeat as intended?

I appreciate any help or insights on what might be causing this problem. Thank you!

I expected the background image to repeat, but it remains as a single instance. How can I fix this issue and make the background image repeat as intended?

Comment: How can image repeat and cover at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

According to me,when we use "backgroundSize: 'cover' " then, our background image is always covers the full height/width so, it won't work as expected when we use "repeat" attribute also.

So, try removing that "cover" line and run your code.